# Getting An AJAX http error occured when updating modules

Tags: http-request

I recently staring getting a

> "An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: http://192.168.1.20/alan_page/authorize.php?batch=1&id=67&op=do StatusText: Internal Server Error ResponseText:" whenever I try to update modules after downloading them.

My Apache logs(last 4 lines after attempting updates read):

> [Mon Dec 21 17:14:35.456511 2015] [:error] [pid 2025] [client 192.168.1.10:50056] PHP  96. FileTransferFTPExtension->chmodJailed() /var/www/drupal/includes/filetransfer/ftp.inc:134, referer: http://192.168.1.20/alan_page/authorize.php?batch=1&op=start&id=67
>   [Mon Dec 21 17:14:35.456529 2015] [:error] [pid 2025] [client 192.168.1.10:50056] PHP  97. FileTransferFTPExtension->chmodJailed() /var/www/drupal/includes/filetransfer/ftp.inc:134, referer: 192.168.1.20/alan_page/authorize.php?batch=1&op=start&id=67
>   [Mon Dec 21 17:14:35.456547 2015] [:error] [pid 2025] [client 192.168.1.10:50056] PHP  98. FileTransferFTPExtension->chmodJailed() /var/www/drupal/includes/filetransfer/ftp.inc:134, referer: 192.168.1.20/alan_page/authorize.php?batch=1&op=start&id=67
>   [Mon Dec 21 17:14:35.456565 2015] [:error] [pid 2025] [client 192.168.1.10:50056] PHP  99. FileTransferFTPExtension->isDirectory() /var/www/drupal/includes/filetransfer/ftp.inc:127, referer: 192.168.1.20/alan_page/authorize.php?batch=1&op=start&id=67

Does anyone have any clues on what might be the problem?

Comment: Please look in the Apache error log.

Comment: Those messages tell you where the problem is but not what the error message is so they're not all that useful as they are.